# Bedeutung von "-schaft" in Landschaft?

Tags: etymology

Mich würde einmal interessieren, ob die Endung "-schaft" im Wort Landschaft womöglich sprachhistorisch etwas mit dem Wort "der Schaft" (Stab, Stange, ...) zu tun hat. Im Englischen gibt es auch die Analogie "landscape" vs. "scape" ([bot.] Schaft).

Comment: Vergleiche *worship* gegen *bishop* einerseits, wohl von *-scopos* "Seher, Beobachter", andererseits *Wertschöpfung* in der behaupteten Bedeutung *scape, schaffen* (vgl. *shape* "form-"). Vergleiche Sinngemäß *Offiziersstab*, *staff, staffer*. Weiters vllt. *Schopf* (wohl früh in der Bed. "Haar", mir aber unklar). Auch: Herkunft von *scapegoat* "Opferlamm" ungewiss, jedoch recht eindeutig. Schwierig abzugrenzen auch *Schöpfkelle*, insofern *Gott* von einer Wurzel "to pour" hergeleitet (cf. en.wiktionary); dazu eventuel auch *Schaufel, Schippe*. Weiters "Schiff" als Kirchenbau, bzw. Noahs Myth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine kurze Einschätzung - nein, wegen zeitlich unterschiedlicher Entstehung.

Im Abschnitt Etymologie findet sich im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Landschaft):

> Landschaft für ‘geographisch zusammenhängendes Gebiet mit einem bestimmten Charakter, mit bestimmten Eigenschaften’, althochdeutsch: lantscaf (8. Jh.), -scaft (um 1000), mittelhochdeutsch: lantschaft ‘Landschaft, Land’, auch ‘Einwohnerschaft des Landes, die versammelten Stände eines Landes’

Im Abschnitt Bedeutung und Herkunft findet sich für `-schaft` im [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-schaft#cite_note-2):

> nachgestelltes Wortbildungselement (Derivatem, Wortbildungsmorphem), das dazu dient, Substantive abzuleiten, um „personale Kollektivbegriffe“ (Burschenschaft …) oder abstrakte Kollektivbegriffe (Landschaft …) zu bilden.
>
> Aus den zuvor selbständigen Substantiven entwickeln sich ab dem 8. - 11. Jahrhundert zahlreiche Komposita mit dem althochdeutschen Suffix „-scaf(t) → goh“, mittelhochdeutsch „-schaft → gmh“ die zwei inhaltliche Kernaspekte beinhalten, „den Gesichtspunkt der Schöpfung und den der (maßvollen) Ordnung“

Der [Althochdeutsche Bedeutungsbaukasten](https://homepages.uni-tuebingen.de/henrike.laehnemann/suffixe.htm#schaft) enthält zu `–schaft (-scaf/-scaft)` folgendes:

> Beide sind Abstraktbildungen zum starken Verbum ‚schaffen’, ahd. skephen, und können auf germ. *skafti- zurückgeführt werden.
>
> Sie bilden zunächst Komposita, deren zweites Glied sich bereits in früherer Zeit zum Kompositionssuffix entwickelt. Aus der ursprünglichen Bedeutung ‚Beschaffenheit eines X’ in abstrakten Substantiven (friunt-, fiantscaf ‚Freund-, Feindschaft’) entwickelt sich ein kollektiver Sinn (heriscaf ‚Volksmenge’), der auch räumlich gefasst wurde (lantscaf ‚Landschaft’).

*Weiterführende Literatur:*
Althochdeutsche -scaf(t)-Bildungen. Studien zum Althochdeutschen 17.
Meineke, Birgit:
Verlag: Göttingen: Vandenhoeck & Ruprecht,, 1991
ISBN 10: 3525203322 / ISBN 13: 9783525203323

Comment: "*Nachher gebildetes Bildungselement das gebildet wurde um Substantive zu bilden ...*", nur halt mit mehr Fremdworten, die kaschieren, dass die keine Ahnung haben und schlecht kopieren.

Comment: Zu dem Substantiv "Schaft" sagst du auch gar nix, der Ansatz "zeitlich unterschiedlicher Entstehung" lässt sich so nicht bestätigen.

Comment: upvotes und accept von 7 die so überrascht sind, dass es sowas wie Altdeutsch gibt, und den Beleg  "8. Jh" daher gar nicht zeitlich einordnen können, ob "unterschiedlich" oder nicht. FML

Answer (score 9):

*Schaft* "Stange, Stab" ist maskulin, auch im Ahd. und Aengl. (*scaft*, *sceaft*). Dazu paßt nengl. *shaft*. [DWB schaft](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=14,2048,31), [DWDS
Schaft](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schaft#etymwb-1), [Etymonline shaft](https://www.etymonline.com/word/shaft#etymonline_v_23323)

Die Ableitungen auf ahd. *-scaf(t)* sind feminin, beim korrespondierenden aengl. *-scipe* (nengl. *-ship*) dagegen maskulin. [DWDS -schaft](https://www.dwds.de/wb/-schaft#etymwb-1), [Etymonline -ship](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ship#etymonline_v_21219)

Als alleinstehendes Wort bedeutet ahd. *scaft* f. "Geschöpf, Gestalt"; so noch im Mhd. Dazu paßt nhd. *schaffen*. [Lexer schaft](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/Lexer?bookref=2,635,34), [BMZ schaft](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/BMZ?lemma=schaft)

Die aengl. Entsprechungen dazu sind *(ge)sceap*, *(ge)sceaft* f. oder n. Zu ersterem paßt nengl. *shape*. [BT](http://lexicon.ff.cuni.cz/html/oe_bosworthtoller/b0435.html), [Etymonline shape](https://www.etymonline.com/word/shape#etymonline_v_23347)

Das angesprochene engl. *scape* "Stamm, Stengel" ist dagegen viel jünger; es wurde im 17. Jahrhundert von lat. *scapus* abgeleitet (welches allerdings tatsächlich verwandt mit *Schaft* sein könnte). [Etymonline scape](https://www.etymonline.com/word/scape#etymonline_v_50258)

Ebenfalls im 17. Jahrhundert wird *landscape* nach Niederländisch *landschap* gebildet (*-schap* entspricht dt. *-schaft*); daher das Suffix *-scape* statt *-ship*. [Etymonline landscape](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=landscape)

Jedenfalls gehören *-schaft* und *-ship* zusammen. Einige ältere Ableitungen, die vor allem im Englischen teilweise durch andere Formen ersetzt wurden: *Freundschaft – friendship*, *Feindschaft* – aengl. *fēondscipe*, *Botschaft* – aengl. *bodscipe*; mit nicht verwandtem Erstglied *Herrschaft* – *lordship*; ausgestorben ahd. *liutscaf* – aengl. *lēodscipe* "Leut" + "-schaft". [AWB liutscaf](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemma=liutscaf)

Comment: Auch eine sehr gute Antwort. Manchmal würde ich gern 2 grüne Häkchen vergeben.